# Vowpal Wabbit contextual bandits

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I am using contextual bandits in VW to optimize the selection of action based on context. I have 4 strategies of recommending products - `A, B, C, D`.

At request time, my service asks VW which action to recommend by sending the following query:

```
1 2 3 4 | ftr1 ftr2 ftr3...
```

Here, 1, 2, 3, 4 are the corresponding actionIds for strategies A, B, C, D.

VW is running in daemon mode as

```
vw -d --quiet --cb_explore 4 --port 26542
```

So VW is running the epsilon greedy policy.

I am not sure how to provide training examples to VW. Right now, I am doing the following.

1. Upon taking each action, I generate a negative example (with positive cost) and send the following negative example to VW.

   `3:1:p | context...`

Here, 3 is the chosen actionId, `p` is the probability with which it was chosen (returned by VW) and 1 is the cost assigned for serving a recommendation.

When I receive a click, I send the following positive example (negative cost) to VW.

`3:-1:p | context...`

Again, 3 is the chosen actionId and `p` is its probability. -1 is the cost for observing the click.

I have the following questions regarding this setup.

1. Do I need to send negative examples to VW at all? Or would only positive examples suffice? Would specifying the probability of selection make it redundant to send all the negative examples? Since there are way more recommendations than click, would sending all negative examples overwhelm VW's model?
2. Right now, the costs (1 and -1) are set without any particular logic. How should those be determined empirically?